# For Else anomaly

Tags: python

I have a list called `spanish` containing loads of sentences, the objective is to input a word and print out all sentences containing that particular word.

**My Code**

```
word = input ("enter key word")
for span in spanish:
    if(word in span):
      print(span, '/n')
else:
     print("sorry that word in not in the list")
```

**The Issue**

If `word` is not in the list it works correctly.
if `word` is in the list it prints all the qualifying sentences correctly but ALSO the else statement.
It's doing my head in.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your properly formatted code

Comment: We love that you're here with us and we cannot reproduce your issue with the information you've provided.

Comment: You should try and edit the post, by putting actual python code. See this link for how to format code in the posts : https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. Please provide us with a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) .

Comment: With this indentation, the `else` is for the `for`, not the `if`

Comment: just add `break` after first `print`. `else` is executed if loop wan't stopped by `break`

Comment: @JL0PD Not sure if that would achieve OPs goal? *"the objective is to input a word and print out **all** sentences containing that particular word"*

Answer (score 1):

### Code example

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

spanish_data = [
    "Catedral",
    "Catedral Metropolitana de la Ciudad de México",
    "Hasta luego",
    "¿De dónde eres?",
]
matches = []

# Input
keyword = input("Enter keyword: ")

# Search
for needle in spanish_data:
    if keyword.lower() in needle.lower():  # e.g., match both Catedral terms
        matches.append(needle)

# Results
if len(matches):
    print(f'Matches for {keyword}: {", ".join(matches)}')
else:
    print(f"No matches for {keyword}")
```

#### Output

`chmod +x script.py`, then
`./script.py`:

```
Enter keyword: Catedral
Matches for Catedral: Catedral, Catedral Metropolitana de la Ciudad de México
```

```
Enter keyword: México
Matches for México: Catedral Metropolitana de la Ciudad de México
```

```
Enter keyword: dónde
Matches for dónde: ¿De dónde eres?
```

```
Enter keyword: t
Matches for t: Catedral, Catedral Metropolitana de la Ciudad de México, Hasta luego
```

```
Enter keyword: no match
No matches for no match
```

### Explanation: `if x in s` vs `for`-statements

#### `for` statement

The `for` loop will repeat (iterate) through each item in `spanish_data`. In your example, it `print`ed multiple times since it'd go through the `else` block each time there was no match.

For more information see [the `for` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) in Python's documentation.

When would you want to use a for statement? Here's a hypothetical example:

#### How does `if keyword.lower() in needle.lower()` work?

- First is uses [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) to make the match case-insensitive. e.g. `"MaTaMoRoS"` is treated like `"matamoros"`.
- The [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) works with `"México"` in `"Catedral Metropolitana de la Ciudad de México"` since [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) is a sequence itself, from python docs:

  > Strings are immutable [sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq) of Unicode code points.

  This means you can see if text exists in text, e.g. `keyword in word`, as well as `keyword in list_items`.

It's a lot to take in at once, but it doesn't contradict: Strings are nothing more than codepoints lumped together.

### Bonus: `if x in s`

These types of statements are called [membership testing](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations).

Use an `if keyword in spanish_data`. This checks `keyword` (a string input) exists in the word [Sequence type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range).

For more details, see [Common sequence operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) on python.org. For specifics, see [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists), [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuples), and [ranges](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges).

### Further optimization: List comprehension

A [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) can be used here since the loop is simple enough. To try, replace the `for` loop:

```py
for needle in spanish_data:
    if keyword.lower() in needle.lower():  # e.g., match both Catedral terms
        matches.append(needle)
```

With this list comprehension:

```py
matches = [needle for needle in spanish_data if keyword.lower() in needle.lower()]
```

Analysis:

```
matches = [needle for needle in spanish_data if keyword.lower() in needle.lower()]
#            ^          ^            ^       ^
#            |          |            |       |
#            |          |            |       +- Condition to filter with
#            |          |            +--------- Sequence being iterated
#            |          +---------------------- Declares var in scope
#            +--------------------------------- Item returned in iteration
```

Comment: The question says that `spanish` contains a list of sentences, not words.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) for the behavior of the `else` clause on loops.

> Loop statements may have an else clause; it is executed when the loop terminates through exhaustion of the iterable (with for) or when the condition becomes false (with while), but not when the loop is terminated by a break statement.

In your case, `break` is not an option because you want to print **all** sentences that match the keyword. For your purpose, you should use a flag that is set to `True` if any sentence contains the word. If not, we will print the error message at the end.

```py
word = input ("enter key word")
found = False
for span in spanish:
    if word in span:
        print(span, end="\n\n")
        found = True
if not found:
     print("sorry that word is not in the list")
```

Comment: That works,, so appreciative of you and all offers to help, THANK YOU Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your ``èlse`is executed in all the cases. You only want it to be executed if you've reached the end of the list and you haven't found your word in any of the sentences. Before you do execute your print that says` not found`you might want to add the condition` reached the last sentence```:

```py
for sentence in spanish:
  if word in sentence:
    print(sentence)
if sentence == spanish[-1] : # reached last sentence and didn't find the word in it 
  print('Not found')
```

Comment: The last `if`'s condition will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to get all the matching sentences:

```
import unidecode

def normalize(sentence: str) -> str:
    """Returns string without accented characters for case-insensitive comparison."""
    return unidecode.unidecode(sentence.casefold())

def main() -> None:
    # From https://www.rosettastone.com/languages/spanish-words
    spanish_sentences = [
        'Buenos días',  #  Good morning
        'Buenas tardes',  #  Good afternoon
        'Buenas noches',  #  Good evening
        'Hola, me llamo Juan',  #  Hello, my name is John
        'Me llamo…',  #  My name is…
        '¿Cómo te llamas?',  #  What’s your name?
        'Mucho gusto',  #  Nice to meet you
        '¿Cómo estás?',  #  How are you?
        'Estoy bien, gracias',  #  I’m well thank you
        'Disculpa. ¿Dónde está el baño?',  #  Excuse me. Where is the bathroom?
        '¿Qué hora es?',  #  What time is it?
        '¿Cómo se dice ‘concert’ en español?',  #  How do you say ‘concert’ in Spanish?
        'Estoy perdido/a',  #  I am lost
        'Yo no comprendo',  #  I do not understand
        'Por favor, habla más despacio',  #  Would you speak slower, please
        'Te extraño',  #  I miss you
        'Te quiero',  #  I love you
    ]
    word = input('Enter key word: ')
    sentences_containing_word = [
        sentence for sentence in spanish_sentences
        if normalize(word) in normalize(sentence)  # Ideally you would want to store the normalized sentences so you don't need to normalize them each time you look up a word.
    ]
    if sentences_containing_word:
        print('\n'.join(sentences_containing_word))
    else:
        print('Sorry that word is not in the sentences list.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Example Usage 1:**

```
Enter key word: te
¿Cómo te llamas?
Te extraño
Te quiero
```

**Example Usage 2:**

```
Enter key word: como
¿Cómo te llamas?
¿Cómo estás?
¿Cómo se dice ‘concert’ en español?
```

**Example Usage 3:**

```
Enter key word: adios
Sorry that word is not in the sentences list
```